# sqlite in vb.net, can't find table even though it exists

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm using the following code (System.Data.SQLite within VB.net):

```
        Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
        Dim SQLcommand As SQLiteCommand
        SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=vault.db;"
        SQLconnect.Open()
        SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
        SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO entries VALUES ('" & appinput.Text & "','" & userinput.Text & "','" & passinput.Text & "')"
        SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQLcommand.Dispose()
        SQLconnect.Close()
        Me.Hide()
```

I get an error back that says it can't find the table "entries"
I know the table exists because I can write to it via the command line through sqlite and through Autoit and can see it and edit it in the SQLite browser when I open the database. I don't understand why VB can't see it (I know it sees and opens the database file just fine). Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the entries table is not in the valut.db database?  Are you sure that the user you are running this code under has access to that schema?  Can you post the specific exception?

Comment: the entries table is there, like I said I can use the command line with SQLite and read and write to it, and I can do the same when I open it with SQLite Browser. It's sqlite, there are no users or permissions existing or needed, just a basic database file with 3 tables.

I'd post the detail, but it is 2500 lines long and I don't know what the important parts are. I'm new to VB.net, but I know SQL quite well, so I know everything is fine with the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your problem is with relative paths (directories).

sqlite will create a database file if it does not exist so you will never get a "db file not found message". The first indication of an incorrect path is "table missing".

My personal experience is that although it goes against my programmers instinct is to alway use an absolute (fully qualified)  path/file name for an sqlite database.

If you put in the full file location like "/var/myapp/vault.db" you should be OK.
If this is likly to move around store pick up the file name from a properties/config file -- 'config file not found' is much easier to deal with than "table not found".

Comment: that solved the problem, but brings up another issue; without the use of a relative path, the program is then limited to a strict install path.

Comment: No its not. You just have to be able to pick up the installed path at runtime and use it to compose the full connection string. .Net makes that pretty easy.

Comment: @James your answer saved me. I had to specify the full path to fix my problem. Funny thing though, the connection string was showing that it was opening the DB and that there was connection. But stating the literal path worked. I'll address how to implement path updates later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

*Argh!*  There are 3 big issues in that code.  Please update it like this to fix two of them:

```
Using cn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=vault.db;"), _
      cmd As New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO entries VALUES (@AppInput, @UserInput, @PassInput)", cn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppInput", appinput.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserInput", userinput.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassInput", passinput.Text);

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

This will prevent sql injection by parameterizing your query instead of substituting values directly and prevent db locking issues by making sure your connection is disposed properly, even if an exception is thrown.

The third problem is that you should **NEVER** store plain-text passwords in your database (or anywhere else for that matter).  Go read up on how to hash values in .Net and hash and salt your password before storing or comparing it.

Once you've done that re-test your code to see if you still get the same errors reported as before.  We need to make sure this didn't solve the problem or introduce something new.  Then we can start addressing the missing table issue, perhaps by checking your [connection string](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/938/4017.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I'll try it, and I know about the plain text passwords, I will be adding encryption, I just wanted to make sure the program writes properly first, encryption comes second.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with SQLite (via .Net) refusing to believe the table existed, even though direct access confirmed it was there. The error could be produced only on one individual machine and not others. Hard coding the path didn't seem to fix the problem. The fix was either to run the program as Administrator or change the DB file to be available to Everyone. Apparently the .Net assembly raises a missing table error when the actual problem is access restrictions.